# Aggregating the value of one variable for each class and each ID

Tags: r, aggregation

I have the following data frame:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
spent <- c(10,10,20,10,10,5,5,5,20)
period <- c("f","c","c","v","v","f","c","c","v")
mean.spent <- c(10,15,15,10,10,5,5,5,20)
df <- data.frame(id,spent,period,mean.spent)
```

what I want is to aggregate the mean spent for each Id in each period as follow:

```
id  f  c  v    
1   10 15 10
2   5  5  20
```

Can you please help me to do this?

Comment: @Arun your proposed edit is the solution. Please don't do that

Comment: @ColeJohnson, I disagree. Arun's edit merely helps others to copy and paste the provided code into an R session to further work towards getting the desired output.

Comment: @Ananda ok but it's generally not a good idea to edit the OP's code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `xtabs()` along with `aggregate()` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 spent = c(10,10,20,10,10,5,5,5,20),
                 period = c("f","c","c","v","v","f","c","c","v"),
                 mean.spent = c(10,15,15,10,10,5,5,5,20))

xtabs(spent ~ id + period, aggregate(spent ~ id + period, df, mean))
#    period
# id   c  f  v
#   1 15 10 10
#   2  5  5 20
```

`aggregate` calculates the mean per group (as grouped by "id" and "period"), and `xtabs` does the transformation into this wider format.

Here's how to make it into a `data.frame`:

```
temp1 <- xtabs(spent ~ id + period, 
               aggregate(spent ~ id + period, df, mean))
data.frame(id = dimnames(temp1)$id, as.data.frame.matrix(temp1))
#   id  c  f  v
# 1  1 15 10 10
# 2  2  5  5 20
```

#### Update: a more direct approach

I always forget about `tapply`, but this example is a good candidate for when it is convenient.

```
tapply(df$spent, list(df$id, df$period), mean)
#    c  f  v
# 1 15 10 10
# 2  5  5 20
```

Comment: Thanks but can I make it a dataframe?

Comment: @AliTamaddoni, sure. Just wrap `xtabs` with "as.data.frame.matrix()". The "id" will be the "row.names", so you'll have to add them back in if you want them as a column.

Comment: @AliTamaddoni, I've added how to convert it to a `data.frame` as part of the answer.

Comment: @Arun, why did you delete your answer? I was just about to vote it up for being a more direct approach to getting to `temp1` -- Anyway, see my update....